# Installing GCC 3.4.6 in RHEL4

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, redhat, rhel

I do the following in command line:

1) wget ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/gcc-3.4.6.tar.bz2

2) tar -jxf gcc-3.4.6.tar.bz2

3) cd gcc-3.4.6

4) cd libstdc++-v3

5) ./configure

And I get the following error:

configure: error: cannot find install-sh or install.sh in ./../..

There is actually an "install-sh" file in the gcc-3.4.6 directory, but that's one directory up the current, not two.

The configure script should look for install-sh in "./.." insted of "./../.." ??

What's wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. wget ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/gcc-3.4.6.tar.bz2
2. tar -jxf gcc-3.4.6.tar.bz2
3. cd gcc-3.4.6
4. ./configure
5. make
6. make install

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: Consider [stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) to keep custom installations in /usr/local in some sane order.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you cd:ing down into libstdc++-v3? I thought the correct way was to just run "make" from the directory you ran configure from.

Comment: The error happens upon running ./configure. I'm not able to run make yet.
There is a configure script in libstdc++-v3 too. And the installation instructions are so confusing that I probably missunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I built a different package that didn't come with a configure script:

```
config/autorun.sh
./configure <options>
make
make install
```